# Git : Ubuntu: Url has no scheme

Tags: git, ubuntu, server

Everything was working fine on my digitalocean droplet where i have laravel applicaton deployed, and today when i tried to do "git pull" i just received :

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01:/var/www/html# git pull
warning: url has no scheme:
fatal: credential url cannot be parsed:
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01:/var/www/html#
```

Any idea how can i fix this? I tryed `apt-get remove git` & then `apt-get install git`. That did not help

Thanks!

Comment: Run `git remote -v` and check that the URLs are valid

Comment: @symlink Yes sir, url is 100% valid.

Comment: There's not really enough information here for us to diagnose the question. It looks like a configuration issue, but you haven't included any details about your configuration. Can you include the output of `git remote -v` in your question? Maybe also `git config --list`?

Comment: @larsks i just removed everything from git config. so git config --list is giving me nothing now. 0 chars. git remote -v is giving me exact repo url on github https://github.com/djokicpn/MyRepoHere

Comment: Maybe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383299/git-pull-server-message-warning-url-has-no-scheme-ipport-fatal-credential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because your URL has no scheme.  In a URL like https://github.com/git/git.git, the scheme is the `https` portion.  When you try to do a pull, you're invoking the credential helper to get credentials, and as of the recent security update, not specifying a scheme is a fatal error.

If you want to use an HTTPS URL, then you need to specify a full, valid URL, including the scheme, which you can do with a command like the following:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/djokicpn/MyRepoHere
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I already fixed it by reinitializing git repo. But this would work as well because it did same thing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue today.
For me, the issue was having 2 blank lines at the bottom of my `git-credentials` file.

1 blank line works fine, but 2 blank lines causes this error.

Comment: Thank you! I only had one blank line and would never have guessed that this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue when I tried to clone an new repo today. The root of the problem was in a credential setup in my .gitconfig file. One of my section headers showed [credential "github.com"] and had to be changed to [credential "https://github.com"]. I'm not sure why this all of a sudden became a problem, but that is what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using **ssh instead of https**. Find how to create and store your ssh credentials, this depends on which git server are you using: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh.
Once you've done that, run this command

```
git remote set-url origin git@your_repo_here.git
```

Once I did that, the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with git 2.17.1

I upgraded git to latest 2.32.0 using the guidance at https://itsfoss.com/install-git-ubuntu/

I used  the following commands to store credentials

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for '<https://username@github.com>':
```

I found that this updated the  ~/.git-credentials by adding the first line. Contents given below.

```
https://<username>:<personal authentication token>@github.com
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=<username>
password=<personal authentication token>
```

Now if I make some changes, commit  and do the push operation, it worked without prompting again for username, password.

For information, my .gitconfig has the following

```
[credential "github.com"]
    helper = cache
        helper= store --file ~/.git-credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

as your problem, you should use old version of git, try to install latest git-version from "https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/how_to_install_git/" as per your system linux, macos etc.my problem was solved, hope this solved your error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

guys, I've got stuck with this recently. The problem was in double credential settings in .gitconfig[image: f]