# Git pull server message : warning: url has no scheme IP:Port , fatal: credential url cannot be parsed IP:Port

Tags: linux, git

Hello i want to clone and pull some git repo to my linux server , i have an issue when running : `git clone` and `git pull` in my server. it says : `warning: url has no scheme  IP:Port , fatal: credential url cannot be parsed  IP:Port`. i tried to set new url with this command :  `git remote set-url origin  http://IP:PORT/my.Git.Server/API_WEBTOOL3.git`. but it doesnt work the same error still appear. Please help my issues :(

Comment: I have the same problem. This "suddenly" (= since today) occurs in an environment where nothing (I know about) has recently changed... wait: My self-hosted gitlab-server has recently (auto) updated to 12.10. Maybe this is the source of the problem. Maybe also yours?

Comment: FYI: At least in my case in fact the URL is complete (https://...) AND git push and pull work just fine. Just this messages before the normal ouput.

Comment: maybe you should be more precise in your question: Add output of git etc. And maybe a bit more formatting for easier reading :-)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output of `git config -l` as a code block?

Comment: ok i'm sorry my bad, i missed that one. bytheway i already update my question

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? In my case the problem came up after upgrading to git `1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7`. I tried installing the older version `git 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.6` and the problem disappeared. But this isn't a solution...

Answer (score 25):

Removing an empty line from `~/.git-credentials` solved the problem for me.

I had the same problem using git on ubuntu and a git credential helper "store". The upgrade to git `1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7` (see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7)) brought the problem. This security update adds more strict checks of the credential URLs. It seems the empty line is misinterpreted as a bad URL.

Comment: can u tell me more spesific sir ? what command should i run ?

Comment: Find where your credentials are stored: Use `git config -l` and find the line `credential.helper=store...`. If there is a filename then use this one, else it's `~/.git-credentials`. Then open this file and remove all empty or other "useless" lines. BTW: It seems there is a patch for git which hopefully will by released soon: https://lore.kernel.org/git/20200427004640.GA28818@Carlos-MBP/T/#m3360508b5ff7c869de433410b699aabd83946c15

Comment: @YosefHeryana if this helped you, please be so kind and do accept this as correct answer.

Comment: @YosefHeryana `nano ~/.git-credentials`, delete the last line, Ctrl+O to save and Ctrl+X to exit.

Answer (score 3):

This should be solved with With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

Recent updates broke parsing of "`credential.<url>.<key>`" where `<url>` is not a full URL (e.g. `[credential "https://"] helper = ...`) stopped working: that has been fixed.

See [commit 9a121b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a121b0d226dd0017318be0d18120aeb766f1235), [commit 6828e59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6828e5972b82f474cc14ca9cb9e01e897f205f4c), [commit 21920cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21920cbd9af489763a62ebb81e1ca188354f833e) (24 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit da05cac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da05cacd8a4e7c3d6d8c84aa2c1d45684717ac95), 05 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a121b0d226dd0017318be0d18120aeb766f1235): handle `credential.<partial-URL>.<key>` again
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Reviewed-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
>
> In the patches for CVE-2020-11008, the ability to specify credential settings in the config for partial URLs got lost. For example, it used to be possible to specify a credential helper for a specific protocol:
>
> ```
> [credential "https://"]
>     helper = my-https-helper
> ```
>
> Likewise, it used to be possible to configure settings for a specific host, e.g.:
>
> ```
> [credential "dev.azure.com"]
>     useHTTPPath = true
> ```
>
> Let's reinstate this behavior.
>
> While at it, increase the test coverage to document and verify the behavior with a couple other categories of partial URLs.

And:

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6828e5972b82f474cc14ca9cb9e01e897f205f4c): optionally allow partial URLs in `credential_from_url_gently()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Reviewed-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
>
> Prior to the fixes for CVE-2020-11008, we were `_very`_ lenient in what we required from a URL in order to parse it into a `struct credential`. That led to serious vulnerabilities.
>
> There was one call site, though, that really needed that leniency: when parsing config settings a la `credential.dev.azure.com.useHTTPPath`.
>   Settings like this might be desired when users want to use, say, a given user name on a given host, regardless of the protocol to be used.

---

Finally:

With the recent tightening of the code that is used to parse various parts of a URL for use in the credential subsystem, a hand-edited credential-store file causes the credential helper to die, which is a bit too harsh to the users.

> Demote the error behaviour to just ignore and keep using well-formed lines instead.

See [commit c03859a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c03859a66525c6bdc5cd3c02b31f06cfdd80b595) (02 May 2020) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
See [commit 20b4964](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20b4964fdf43491494122fbd297b2da7d66663b2) (28 Apr 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 933fdf8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/933fdf8784d0fedaa259c6caf90115cfa7d21184), 08 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential-store`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c03859a66525c6bdc5cd3c02b31f06cfdd80b595): ignore bogus lines from store file
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Dirk</sup>
>   <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
>   <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>   <sup>Based-on-patch-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
>
> With the added checks for invalid URLs in credentials, any locally modified store files which might have empty lines or even comments were reported failing to parse as valid credentials.

(reported in this very page by the OP)

> Instead of doing a hard check for credentials, do a soft one and therefore avoid the reported fatal error.
>
> While at it add tests for all known corruptions that are currently ignored to keep track of them and avoid the risk of regressions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.  adding the URL `"dev.azure.com"` to the section `[credential "dev.azure.com"]` in the file `.gitconfig` helped me to fix it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What helped for me was the following:

With

```
git config -l
```

I found out that there was a setting

```
credential.[URL].username=[SOME-USERNAME]
```

I deleted this using

```
git config --unset credential.[URL].username
```

Then things worked again.